# Update $scope in an $interval function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I have a login page designed using `angular-material`. Along with this I also have a password manager chrome extension which works well on many other websites.

What I am trying to achieve is to make the login page compatible with my password manager extension. The extension is provided with the `id` of the fields, next it fetches the data to be inserted into it and in the last it fills the input with the fetched value. This is done using pure JS like below:

```
var inputBox = document.getElementById(fieldId);
if (typeof inputBox !== "undefined" && inputBox !== null) {
    inputBox.click();
    inputBox.focus();
    inputBox.value = fetchedValue;
}
```

However, on the login page, I have a dialog that displays the form fields. The extension is able to find the fields using the id and also able to insert the value. But even after that the form validation error for `required` condition is shown.

I tried to replicate the behaviour in angular using the below code:

```
$scope.user = {
    username: '',
    password: ''
};

$interval(function() {
    var inputBox = document.getElementById("username");
    console.log(inputBox);
    if (typeof inputBox !== "undefined" && inputBox !== null) {
        inputBox.click();
        inputBox.focus();
        inputBox.value = "test";
    }
}, 2000, 1);
```

The `username` field is bound to `$scope.user.username` but still upon insertion, the scope is not modified.

Here's the JSFiddle where the issue is replicated: https://jsfiddle.net/prerak6962/fxwmda5w/2/

Comment: This is not how Angular works.  Angular used events to update the `$scope` properties in the background;  using JavaScript to change the value of an input box does not trigger an event, and therefore will not update the angular monitored properties.  if this is done **outside an angular context**, you can call that function from angular followed by a `$scope.$apply()`;  if, however, this is called from **inside an angular context**, like `$interval`, then you must adhere to angular rules, and modify the property, not the DOM value.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just:

```
$interval(function() {
            var inputBox = document.getElementById("username");
            console.log(inputBox);
            if (typeof inputBox !== "undefined" && inputBox !== null) {
                inputBox.focus();
                $scope.user.username = "test";
            }
        }, 2000, 1);
```

Angular do not watch values in inputs, instead it listen to DOM-events to track changes, when you change element content manually - angular will never know that something changed.

P.S. Angular is PLAIN JS. There is no 'magic'. For example, this strange code will work:

```
var user = {
            username: '',
            password: ''
        };
var rootScope;        

(function() {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('chipsDemo', [])
        .controller('BasicDemoCtrl', DemoCtrl);

    function DemoCtrl($scope, $rootScope) {
        $scope.user = user;
        rootScope = $rootScope;
    }
})();

setInterval(function() {
  user.password = new Date().getTime();
  rootScope.$apply();
}, 1000);
```

Comment: I want to change the value using pure JS as my extension is developed using pure JS. I cannot use anything else. I have added the `$interval` part just to reproduce the behaviour using a single application. But in reality there are two different apps (one website and one chrome extension).

Comment: I added some comment, you can manipulate Angular object from anywhere with ease.

Comment: Yes, I read it. But there's no angular in my extension. So I cannot use any angular services in it.

Comment: If you can run js - you can. I.e. this will return digest time for any angular site (run from console): angular.element(document).injector().invoke(['$rootScope',function($rootScope) { var a = performance.now(); $rootScope.$apply(); return performance.now()-a; }])